# System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.ni.dll

Tags: c#, windows, windows-10-iot-core

im getting this error when running my code:
*Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
WinRT information: Access Denied*

Exception is thrown when this line is arrived:
*await recog.ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync();*

```
namespace yesorno
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Language newlanguage = new Language("en-US");
            SpeechRecognizer recog = new SpeechRecognizer(newlanguage);

            StorageFile mygr = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"Grammar\Commands.xml");
            SpeechRecognitionGrammarFileConstraint gc = new SpeechRecognitionGrammarFileConstraint(mygr);
            recog.Constraints.Add(gc);
            SpeechRecognitionCompilationResult cr = await recog.CompileConstraintsAsync();
            Debug.Write(cr.Status);
            if (cr.Status==SpeechRecognitionResultStatus.Success)
            {
                await recog.ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync();
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

        private void recog_result(SpeechContinuousRecognitionSession sender,SpeechContinuousRecognitionResultGeneratedEventArgs args)
        {

            switch (args.Result.Text)
            {
                case "yes":
                    Debug.Write("yes");
                    break;
                case "no":
                    Debug.Write("no");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Tried it on Windows 10 and Win10 ioT

Comment: Put a break point on the switch statement and check if the value of args.Results.Text is a string.

Comment: Have you added `<DeviceCapability Name="microphone" />` in Package.appxmanifest?

Comment: Have you added <DeviceCapability Name="microphone" /> in Package.appxmanifest?

Comment: thanks Rita Han this was the solution!!